# Can mediafoundation allow multiple clients to simultaneously access a single webcam device?

Tags: c++, webcam, video-capture, ms-media-foundation, webcam-capture

I intend to build an adapter exposing methods such as "StartCapture" and "StopCapture" using mediafoundation and would like multiple clients to be able to access these methods simultaneously from a single webcam device.

Currently the code I've seen in samples allows only for 1 stream to capture data in a file (the other ends up being empty).

Does mediafoundation allow for simultaneous device access? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video input devices have traditionally been exclusive use resources. Once one client started a session, other clients cannot use the camera before it's released by the running session.

Windows 10 Anniversary Update introduced so called Frame Server, which is a middleware layer that, as was advertised, shared the camera between clients under certain circumstances.

> [This puts an end to the "exclusive" use of devices, and it's arguably a change that Windows should have made long ago. Third-party software for sharing cameras between applications exists, but the operating system should support this scenario natively, as it already does for audio devices.](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/08/windows-10-anniversary-update-breaks-most-webcams/)

To my best knowledge this does not work. At least it did not work for a few cameras I tried, and as of now the sharing does not work with Windows 10 Creators Update. Quote possibly though certain cameras/modes exist for which the feature is implementing the sharing.